# OPENROWSET file with parameters into sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm reading this file with next query:

```
DECLARE @x xml;

SET @x = (
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Attachments\arch.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS [Document]
);
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES    (  'http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital' as Timbre, 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as cfdi) 
select   
TimbreUUID = Timbre.value('@UUID', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM @x.nodes('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/Timbre:TimbreFiscalDigital') a(timbre)
```

This query gets a field called `UUID`, here all good, but now I need that instead that `OPENROWSET (bulk 'string', SINGLE_BLOB)` use a string this use a parameter.

How to do that OPENROWSET use a parameter?

For example:

```
declare @param varchar(max)='C:\Attachments\arch.xml'
SET @x = (
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @param, SINGLE_BLOB) AS [Document]
);
```

**Sorry, I have some restrictions on the network, so I can not use the editor properly**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Yes, i will add the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with next code:

```
declare @path nvarchar(max)=('C:\EME870831T20.xml')
declare @results table (x xml)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=N'SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(x AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ''encoding="utf-16"'', ''encoding="utf-8"'') AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@path+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)'
INSERT INTO @results EXEC (@sql) ;WITH 
XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as cfdi,'http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital' as tfd)
SELECT xmldata.value('(@UUID)', 'varchar(100)') AS item_id  
FROM @results  CROSS APPLY
x.nodes('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital') AS a(xmldata);
```